# Что означает "В лучших x.xx% за <промежуток времени>"?

Tags: обсуждение

Когда захожу в свой профиль или профиль любого другого участника сообщества, вижу надпись по типу **в лучших 6% за год** или **в лучших 0.05% за всё время**.

Вопрос: что именно означает данный процент, какой процент лучше: высокий или низкий?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Этот процент указывает как много пользователей набрало больше очков репутации чем вы за заданный период времени.

Таким образом

> в лучших 6% за год

будет означать, что 6% пользователей набрало как минимум столько же или больше репутации.

Следовательно, чем меньше процент в данной статистике — тем лучше (если использовать критерий "лучше" как стоять в рейтинге выше).